# The probability that the intersection of two sets has a determinate size

Tags: probability-theory

Suppose I have a finite set A and two subsets B, C $\subseteq$ A. I'd like to know what's the probability that the intersection of those two sets is greater than or equal to some number.

More specifically, I'd like to know the probability that the intersection of B and C equals some specific proportion of B (or C).

For instance, if I have the sets A = [0,100], B = [50,100] and C = [40,60], I know that the intersection of B and C takes up 20% of B and 50% of C. Now, supposing I have some definite set A, some definite subset B $\subseteq$ A and a random subset C $\subseteq$ A, what's the probability that C $\cap$ B takes up x% or more of B? And vice-versa?

I'm not even sure my question makes sense, but there it is.

Comment: a) You introduce $A$ as a finite set; does that mean that the notation $A=[0,100]$ is intended to refer only to the integers between (and including) $0$ and $100$? b) Presumbly wherever you have $\in$ you meant $\subseteq$? c) What's a random subset of $A$? Do you want to pick one uniformly among all $2^{|A|}$ subsets of $A$? Or among all subsets of a certain size?

Comment: a)Yes, that's what I meant. But now that I think about it, I wonder what it'd look like if A weren't finite?
b)Yes, that is so ^^
c)The first one. I want both the size and the members of this "random subset" to be equally likely.

Comment: If I interpret your answer to c) correctly, it's contradictory. In my suggestion of picking uniformly among all $2^{|A|}$ subsets of $A$, the possible sizes of the subset wouldn't be equally likely -- rather, the probability of picking a subset of size $k$ would be $\displaystyle\binom{|A|}k2^{-|A|}$ and would thus depend on $k$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that B and C are subsets of A, |A| = a, |B| = b, |C| = c.  To answer the question, is the intersection of B and C exactly size d, for d $\leq$ b, c, fix B.  now, an arbitrary choice of C is a selection of c elements from A; then there are $_a C_c$ possible choices for C, and $_b C_d \cdot _{a-b}C_{c-d}$ of them give an intersection of size d.

Answer (score 1):

Let $|A| = n$ and let $P(k)$ denote the probability that the intersection $D$ of arbitrary $B, C \subseteq A$ has cardinality exactly $k$ for $0 \le k \le n$. We get
$$P(k) = \frac{\text{#of ways of choosing $B$, $C$ with $|D| = k$}}{\text{# of ways of choosing $B$, $C$}}$$

Note first that there are $\binom nk$ choices for $D$. For $B$ we can choose arbitrarily from the $2^{n-k}$ sets containing $D$. For $C$, our choice is less free: we have to ensure the intersection with $B$ is exactly $D$, and not more.

So we break it into cases: If $B$ has size $k$, then there is one choice for $B$, and we can choose $C$ arbitrarily from $2^{n-k}$ possibilities. If $B$ has size $k + 1$, then there are $\binom {n-k}1$ choices for $B$ and $2^{n-k-1}$ choices for $C$. Denoting $m = n-k$ and summing, there are
$$\sum_{j = 0}^m 2^{m-j} \binom mj = 3^m$$
possible choices for $B, C$ with intersection $D$. (Calculating the above sum is a fun exercise.) Thus there are 
$$3^{n-k} \binom nk$$
possible ways of choosing the subsets with the desired property. Since there are $(2^n)^2 = 4^n$ ways of choosing any two subsets of $A$, we get
$$P(k) = \frac{3^{n-k} \binom nk}{4^n}.$$

(If this solution is in error, please point it out! I wouldn't put my house on it just yet. A comforting thing is that $\sum_{k=0}^n P(k) = 1.$)